# How to add "flag" parameter to the android Uri

Tags: android, uri

guyz!

Firstly, I'd like to explain, what do I mean under "flag query parameter".
This is a parameter that doesn't have a value, so, the query looks like this:
`https://website.com?aaa=bbb&flag&ccc=ddd`.

And I have found out today, that there is no simple way to add flags to the `android.net.Uri` in Android.

The variant I have:

```java
String flagParameter = "flag";

// create the Uri.
Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://website.com");
uri = uri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("aaa", "bbb").build();
// uri => http://website.com?aaa=bbb

StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(uri.getQuery());
if (builder.length() > 0) { // always true in this case
  builder.append("&");
}
builder.append(flagParameter);

uri = uri.buildUpon().encodedQuery(builder.toString()).build();
// uri => http://website.com?aaa=bbb&flag
```

Good news are when we are appending more parameters after. It doesn't break the uri. So if we add this line:

```
uri = uri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("ccc", "ddd").build();
```

The output of the uri would be:

```
http://website.com?aaa=bbb&flag&ccc=ddd
```

---

Do you have any other ways to add flag parameter to the uri?

Comment: `builder.append(FLAG_PARAM);` ?? We cannot see what you are doing here. The same for the rest of your code. And for the whole i think you create a problem where there is no one.

Comment: A parameter that does not have a value would look like `?aaa=bbb&flag=&ccc=ddd`

Comment: If you add a parameter via `uri.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("flag", "").build()` - yes, it would look like `flag=` in the query. But not with the approach described above.

PS: I've updated the code a little with comments and a bit of details.

Comment: You have not told us why the server would accept `&flag` and would have troubles with `&flag=`. For what all the fuss?

Comment: For the rest i do not understand that you mess around with query builder and string builder where you simply could concatenate the url together from strings. There is nothing simpler than building an url with query parameters yourself.

Comment: UriBuilder encodes the symbols in the query (if using query() and not encodedQuery()) which should not be done with String concatenations. There's no need to do things from scratch that are already implemented in specialized classes. And, regarding `flag=` - this is a fully valid variant, but, I'm afraid, there are exceptions on the client side, who will be parsing the Uri. And if the client side would require to send flags without `=` symbol - here's the solution.